# Find area under $y=-x^3$ from x=-3 to x=0 using the Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

How can I find the area under $y=-x^3$ from $x=-3$ to $x=0$ using the Riemann sum?

let $h = 3/n$

$x_i =-3 + i/n$

\begin{align}
A &= R_n \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} {\sum_{i=1}^{n} h (-(x_i)^3)} \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} h{\sum_{i=1}^{n} -(x_i)^3 } \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} h{\sum_{i=1}^{n} -(-3 + i/n)^3 }
\end{align}

Hopefully somebody can provide some guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\int\limits_0^3x^3dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right)^3\frac{3}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{81n^2(n+1)^2}{4n^4}=\frac{81}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  There's a formula: $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3=(\dfrac {n(n+1)}2)^2$.

And a formula: $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\dfrac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$.

And there's the Gauß sum:  $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\dfrac {n(n+1)}2$.

Finally,  use $(-3+\dfrac in)^3=(-3)^3+3(-3)^2(\dfrac in)+3(-3)(\dfrac in)^2+(\dfrac in)^3$.

Comment: I know the formula and I'm able to use it when x is positive. But I'm very confused how to get this to work when x goes from -3 to 0.

Comment: Well, looks like I overcomplicated it.  Just note that it's the opposite of the sum from $0$ to $3$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you recommend summing starting at the origin, rather than from x=-3? If so, could you show me how to get started?

Comment: Let's try it.   It looks like @Michael Rozenberg's answer is quite good.   If you partition $[0,3]$, you get $x_i=\dfrac {3i}n$, right?   But this is clearly just the negative of the sum starting at $-3$ and ending at $0$.

Comment: So we have two ways of doing it.  The second is shorter and more clever, I think.